# Give id to tags in TinyMCE, using PHP + Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tinymce, wysiwyg

I want to add an autoincremental ID to all the

tags (or any tag, for that matter) in any text I save on the tinymce editor. For example:

```
<p> Hey </p>
<p> This is an example </p>
<p> Thanks </p>

I want this to be stores in the db as:

<p id=1> Hey </p>
<p id=2> This is an example </p>
<p id=3> Thanks </p>
```

Is there any way of doing this in TinyMCE, PHP, jQuery..? I'm trying to do it via PHP but I haven't found a way yet.

Is this possible? Thanks.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$page->text = preg_replace_callback('/<p/',function($m){ static $count = 1; return '<p id='.$count++; }, $page->text);
```

But I don't like it at all.

Comment: can you show proper html  and your attempts  ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, gonna edit my question with it

Answer (score 0):

ended up solving this issue. Here is what I did:

```
        $content = preg_replace_callback("/<p|<h1|<h2|<h3|<h4|<table|<ul|<ol/",
        function($m)
        { 
            static $i = 1; 

            return $m[0].' id="item_'.$i++.'">'; 
        }, 
        $content
    );
```

Which basically searchs for all matches within the list of tags I allow in the wysiwyg and replaces the "<tag" with "<tag id="item_X""